# Highcharts: Add different symbol based on Y value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to add a different series symbol based on the Y value it represents in the chart (i.e A value of 1 = sad symbol) but I've come stuck. What I have at the minute just results in the chart falling back to the default symbol. Any ideas? The snippet in question is the If statement within the series array.

```
var moodList = ["very-sad","sad","ok","happy","very-happy"];
  var moodDict = {"very-sad":0, "sad":1, "ok":2, "happy":3, "very-happy":4};


  $(function () {
    var chart;
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
             renderTo: 'highchart-chart',
             defaultSeriesType: 'column',
             type: "line",
             style: {
              fontFamily: 'proxima-nova-soft'
             }
         },
         title: {
             text: 'Your mood over time'
         },
         credits: {
          enabled: false
         },
         legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
         subtitle: {
             enabled: false
         },
         xAxis: {
             type: 'datetime',
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'Mood'
             },
             labels: {
                  formatter: function() {
                      return moodList[this.value];
                  }
              }
         },
         colors: ['#2195AD'],
         legend: {
             layout: 'vertical',
             backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
             align: 'center',
             verticalAlign: 'top',
             x: 100,
             y: 70
         },
         tooltip: {
             formatter: function() {
                 return Highcharts.dateFormat("%H:%M", this.x) +': <b>I felt '+ moodList[this.y] + '</b>';
             },
             borderRadius: 0,
             borderWidth: 0,
             shadow: false,
             backgroundColor: '#083546',
             style: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                padding: '10px'

             }
         },
         plotOptions: {
             line: {
                 pointPadding: 0.2,
                 borderWidth: 0
             },
             series: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                marker: {
                  radius: 5,
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  symbol: 'url(../images/ok.svg)',
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20
                }
             },
             areaspline: {
              fillOpacity: 0.1
             }
         },
         series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
             data: (function() {
              var moods = <?php echo json_encode($mood);?>;
              var dates = <?php echo json_encode($json_date,$row);?>

              var data = [];
              var moodImg;

              if (moodDict[moods[i]] == 0) {
                moodImg = "url(../images/very-sad.svg)";
              } else if(moodDict[moods[i]] == 1) {
                moodImg = "url(../images/sad.svg)";
              } else if(moodDict[moods[i]] == 2) {
                moodImg = "url(../images/ok.svg)";
              } else if(moodDict[moods[i]] == 3) {
                moodImg = "url(../images/happy.svg)";
              } else if(moodDict[moods[i]] == 4) {
                moodImg = "url(../images/very-happy.svg)";
              }

              for (var i = 0; i < moods.length; i++) {

                data.push({
                  x: new Date(dates[i]),
                  y: moodDict[moods[i]],
                  marker: {
                    symbol: moodImg,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20
                  }
                });
              }

              return data;
             }())
         }]
     });
     });
```

Comment: Try `moodImg = "url('../images/sad.svg')";` Your first url is missing the closing bracket too.

Comment: @artm Doh! Thanks for that. Unfortunately didn't sort the issue out. Still defaulting to the original marker symbol.

Comment: You full `if ( ... ) { } else if ( ...) { } ...` statements should be inside `for` loop. Otherwise, `i` is undefined and probably you have errors in the JS console.